# A straight line through origin meets parallel lines $4x+2y=9$ and $2x+y+6=0$ at P and Q. Find PQ segment ratio by origin

Tags: coordinate-systems

Let the equation of line be $y=mx$

Then 
$$2x+y=\frac 92$$
$$2x+mx=\frac 92$$
$$x=\frac{9}{2(2+m)}$$

$$y=\frac{9m}{2(2+m)}$$for the second line 
$$x=\frac{-6}{m+2}$$
$$y=\frac{-6m}{m+2}$$
Let (0,0) divide it in the ratio k:1
$$0=k\frac{9}{2(m+2)}+\frac{-6}{m+2}$$
$$k=\frac 43$$
But the answer given is $\frac 34$.

Now this isn’t simply a perspective problem, because both options 4/3 and 3/4 were present. How do we tell which one is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the question refers to P and $4x+2y=9$ first, and Q and $2x+y +6=0$ second. So, it is logical to assume that the ratio refers to $\frac{OP}{OQ}$.

Also, the ratio can be conveniently found as the ratio of the distances $d_P$ and $d_Q$ between the origin and the two parallel lines, because the distance line, PQ and the two parallel lines form a pair of similar right triangles. Thus,

$$\frac{OP}{OQ}=\frac{d_P}{d_Q}=\frac{\frac{|0+0-9|}{\sqrt{4^2+2^2}}}{\frac{|0+0+6|}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}}}=\frac{\frac92}6=\frac34$$

Answer (score 0):

Technically, both are correct. The given answer is ${3\over 4}$ because most textbooks assume the ration to be $1:k$ not $k:1$

Comment: That doesn’t feel right, especially since they gave both answers in the options. If such discrepancy were to arise, they would have avoided giving both of them.

Comment: Well then you can assume that since they want ratio in which the origin O cuts PQ, they are referring to OP:OQ.

Answer (score -2):

First, do you see that the origin lies **between** P and Q?  It *can't* divide PQ in ratio "4/3" because that is larger than 1 and implies that that the origin is NOT in the interval.

Comment: Doesn’t that happen when the ratio is negative? I don’t understand

Comment: If the origin was not in the interval, there would be minus sign.